# fclose causing exc_bad_access

Tags: c, exc-bad-access, stdio

I can't figure out why this fclose() in my c program is causing bad access. It was working fine and then I changed the if condition to only print when the strings do not equal eachother and suddenly it started causing problems. apart from the bad access error, it is also not printing anything to "newfile.txt"

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>



    int main()
    {

        FILE * cFile;
        FILE *outputfile;

        FILE *newfile;
        cFile = fopen("input.in", "r");
        if (cFile == NULL){
        printf("bad input file");


        }
        newfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w+");


    if (newfile == NULL){
        printf("bad newfile");

    }
        char tempstring[15];
        char tempstring2[15];

          //get each line in the cFile
       while (fscanf(cFile, "%15s", tempstring) != EOF) {


           outputfile = fopen("outputlotnum.txt", "r"); //open/(or reopen) outputfile  to check lines
          if (outputfile == NULL){
        printf("bad outputfile");
        }
            //get each line in the outputfile
           while(fscanf(outputfile, "%15s", tempstring2) != EOF){

                 //if the line from cFile doesn't match the line from outputfile,
                 //then go ahead and print the line to the newfile.txt
               if (strcmp(tempstring, tempstring2) != 0){

                    fprintf(newfile,"%15s \n", tempstring2);

               }

                 //else don't print anything and continue on to the next line

           }

           fclose(outputfile); //close the outputfile after checking all the lines for a match

       }

        fclose(newfile); //throws bad access
        fclose(cFile);


        return 0;

    }
```

Comment: If `fopen()` fails, it returns `NULL`. **Do check that.**

Comment: I checked it and none of them are returning NULL

Comment: it is really strange because the three files already exist. two of the three are already filled with some kind of text, and newfile is the one that is empty.

Comment: Always put a bounds check when reading strings from input sources— **never** trust user input, whether it be from files, console I/O, or the network.  With `fscanf()`, you can do `fscanf(file, "%14s", tempstring)` to read at most 14 characters and a null terminator.

Comment: I tried doing what you suggested with %15s and it still is causing a problem.

Comment: often times when something crashes somewhere it shouldn't, what it really means is you messed up your memory somewhere else (usually a double free), but it didn't crash until somewhere later.

Comment: I just ended up doing it in c++. doing it in c for some reason was making it weird.

Answer (score 1):

Some reasons for library functions seg faulting include passing bad parameters into the function or that you have a memory scribbler.  I suspect that in your case you have overflowed one or both temp string arrays on the stack and have corrupted the file handles. It's generally not a safe operation to fscanf/scanf into a buffer unless you can guarantee that the string you read will fit into that buffer.

To confirm this you could print out the file handles immediately after open, and again before close.  They should be the same.  If they are not then you have accidentally overwritten them.

Comment: I tried doing fscanf with %15s and it is still giving me an error.

Comment: and I checked each file handle to see if any were null and none were null. I am only writing out to newfile and I opened it in w+ mode.

Comment: It's not a case of them being NULL.  If your fscanf overwrites the file handles then they will be corrupt, but not NULL.  The file i/o libraries do little to no checking that the file handle you passed to them is valid and will look up their internal data structure based on the handle you provided, even if it is wrong.